# Prevent pushing an object without values to mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

My Issue is I don't know how to check if all values of an object is empty so that the database does not get all details of an item blank. So I want to save an object with at least one value in it to mongoose. As it stands now when I edit supplier brand information, it always push empty supplier data to mongoose schema.

```
const editBrand = asyncHandler(async (requestObject, responseObject) => {
  const id = requestObject.params.id;
  const supplierInfo = {};
  const { name, madeIn } = await Brand.findById(id);
  if (
    name !== requestObject.body.name ||
    madeIn !== requestObject.body.madeIn
  ) {
    requestObject.body.slug = slugify(
      requestObject.body.name + " " + requestObject.body.madeIn
    );
  }
  if (requestObject.body.category) {
    const { id } = await Category.findOne({
      name: requestObject.body.category,
    });
    requestObject.body.category = id;
  }
  if (requestObject.body.supplier) {
    supplierInfo.name = requestObject.body.supplier.name
      ? format(requestObject.body.supplier.name)
      : undefined;
    supplierInfo.phone = requestObject.body.supplier.phone || undefined;
    supplierInfo.email = requestObject.body.supplier.email || undefined;
    supplierInfo.address = requestObject.body.supplier.address || undefined;
  }
  const update = await Brand.findByIdAndUpdate(
    id,
    {
      name: requestObject.body.name || undefined,
      madeIn: requestObject.body.madeIn || undefined,
      slug: requestObject.body.slug || undefined,
      category: requestObject.body.category || undefined,
      manufacturer: requestObject.body.manufacturer || undefined,
      $push: { supplier: supplierInfo || undefined },
    },
    { new: true, runValidators: true }
  );
  if (!update) {
    responseObject
      .status(417)
      .json({ message: "Unable to update record, please try again." });
  } else {
    responseObject.status(200).json(update);
  }
});
```

Please guide me on how to achieve this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `$push` condition only if `supplier` is defined:

```
let updatedData = {
    name: requestObject.body.name || undefined,
    madeIn: requestObject.body.madeIn || undefined,
    slug: requestObject.body.slug || undefined,
    category: requestObject.body.category || undefined,
    manufacturer: requestObject.body.manufacturer || undefined,
  };
  if (requestObject.body.supplier) {
    supplierInfo.name = requestObject.body.supplier.name
      ? format(requestObject.body.supplier.name)
      : undefined;
    supplierInfo.phone = requestObject.body.supplier.phone || undefined;
    supplierInfo.email = requestObject.body.supplier.email || undefined;
    supplierInfo.address = requestObject.body.supplier.address || undefined;
    updatedData = {
      ...updatedData,
      $push: { supplier: supplierInfo },
    };
  }
  const update = await Brand.findByIdAndUpdate(id, updatedData, {
    new: true,
    runValidators: true,
  });
```